# Filtering combinatorial background in $B_0$ -> $\mu^+ \mu^- K^{*0}$ decay

Tags: particle-physics, data-analysis, large-hadron-collider

We are looking to isolate a signal representing this decay from all possible background candidates produced in a pp collision in the LHCb. We have already dealt with all the peaking backgrounds (J/Psi branch resonance, particle identification mismatch, etc.) using machine learning trained on simulated datasets. We are now looking to deal with the combinatorial background using machine learning as well. The idea is to train our model on the high mass region ($m_{K\pi\mu\mu}>5350 ~$MeV/$c^2$), which we have determined has negligible levels of signal (the mass distribution of the signal follows a crystal ball function centered at about 5280 MeV/$c^2$ with a standard deviation of about 15, depending on $q^2$). Once trained, we will apply this code to the whole dataset and let it filter out the combinatorial background.

Is this method of filtering out combinatorial background valid or not? It seems logically consistent to me, but my gut says that this is a little like having a marble cube and removing everything that doesn't look like a statue, i.e. manipulating the data to fit our expectations.

Comment: subject is not clear to me ,as you discuss it. Th PDG give the mass of the $B^0$ as 5279.58 ± 0.17 MeV.  This will give a peak in the invariant mass  . You mean you want to separate the particles that come directly from the decay from the backround on which the invariant mass of the $B^0$ is seen?

Comment: Yes, we want to separate particles that came directly from this B0 decay from particles that are from combinatorial background. The invariant mass of our B0 candidates right now is distributed according to a combination of a crystal ball function (signal) and and exponential decay (background). We would like to reduce the background as much as possible using machine learning.

Comment: I think your fear of "manipulating the data to fit our expectations" is ground less. As you are not throwing away data, but have devised a method by which the probability of a specific track coming from a true decay is estimated.

Comment: Your so-called "machine learning" should separate signal and background by their properties (difference in kinematics, topology...), the same way as any other selection requirement such as the particle ID you mentioned. A standard check is to apply your "machine learning" to a set of pure background and make sure no fake signal arises.

Comment: Have you shared these worries with your colleagues? They might know the context better and can provide a more informed explanation, than random people on the internet.

Comment: I have brought it up, they believe it was not an issue. I still felt uneasy about it, so I asked here